# Как настроить кэширование Nginx с cookies?

Tags: laravel, nginx, cookie, кэширование

Использую в проекте на laravel 7 связку PHP-FRM7.0 + NGINX.

Скорость ответа сервера 500-600 мс. Это очень много.
После включения в игнор кукис (**proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie**), ответ получается на порядок быстрее — 20-30 мс.

В cookies хранится имя сессии.

Как настроить NGINX/laravel чтобы не игнорировать cookies и увеличить скорость ответа сервера?

Как ещё можно сохранить имя сессии, чтобы сервер отвечал быстро?

Comment: может все таки fpm, а не frm? Похоже, что у Вас либо очень большая нагрузка и fpm не справляется, либо код очень тяжелый (к примеру, бежит в базу и тянет много данных). Нужно смотреть глубже

Comment: Спасибо за направление. Присмотрюсь к запросам в базу.